# How to get the value of a dynamic dropdown list and display with React js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the value of a dynamic dropdown list populated from an API and display the selected value on the screen. Could someone point out what I am doing wrong and help me with what should I be doing differently? I am able to have the list populated, but the value is not displayed at the `<h1>` tag and when I select an option I get an error:

> TypeError: races.map is not a function

Here is what I have so far:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [races, setRaces] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRacesHandler();
  }, []);

  async function fetchRacesHandler() {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.open5e.com/races');
    const data = await response.json();
    setRaces(data.results);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <select value={races} onChange={e => setRaces(e.target.value)}>
        {races.map((item, index) =>
          <option
            key={index}
            value={item.name}
          >
            {item.name}
          </option>
        )}
      </select>
      <h1>{races.name}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thanks ever so much for the help!

Comment: You likely need to differentiate between the state that has a collection of `races` and a selected `race`. In other words, the API result goes into `races` and the selected race needs to go into a new `useState` variable.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for the help. It really worked out as you mentioned. I created a new useState and passed the values to the select tag. Do you mind if I ask you another question that just came up? How do I set the initial value of the option tag as blank or as a pre defined text, such as: "Select an option"? Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`races.map` is not a function because races is not an array. Your problem is in `setRaces(data.results)`. You need to do something like `setMyArray(oldArray => [...oldArray, newElement])` so in your example, you would do `setRaces(races => [...races, data.results])`

I'm not able to test this code but let me know if it doesn't work and we can go from there!

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for the response. When I replaced setRaces(data.results) for setRaces(races => [...races, data.results]), I got my dropdown list with no values. Although I followed crashmstr tip and I was able to make it work creating a new useState and passing the variables to the select onChange and to the <h1> tag. Thank you again for the time and to reply my question.